# Convex hull of $G_\delta$ set is $G_\delta$?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, metric-spaces

Consider a function space $X$ (of functions mapping from $S\subset \mathbb{R}^d$ to reals) and endow it with a metric $d$. Consider a $G_\delta$ subset $X'\subset X$: is the convex hull of $X'$ also a $G_\delta$ set? If this is not true in general, under which conditions on the metric $d$ is this the case?

Comment: This might be a stupid comment, but are there convex sets that are not $G_\delta$?

Comment: @daw If $f$ is a discontinuous linear functional on a Banach space (which exists by the axiom of choice) then its kenel is not $G_\delta$ by https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2425793/if-operatornameker-f-is-a-g-delta-set-in-x-then-f-is-continuous

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is: no. Dubins and Freedman

https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.pjm/1103033793

showed (Theorem 3.22) that there is a $G_\delta$ subset of the unit cube in three  dimensional Euclidean space whose convex hull is not Borel. Thus, in particular, the latter can't be $G_\delta$.